# How do I group by generic field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a table with a status field and I want to know how many records of each status I can do a simple group by. And how about if I want to know the count for 2 records and the count for all the others.

In other words I want this:

```
Status   Count
-------- -----
Success   X
Running   Y
Failure   Z
```

but *Failure* is **`not`** ***Failure*** on the table, it contains the actual error message, so I want everything that's different that **Success** and **Running**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case when Status <> 'Success' 
             and Status <> 'Running' 
            then 'Failure' 
            else Status 
        end Status, 
       count (*) [Count]
from atable
group by case when Status <> 'Success' 
               and Status <> 'Running' 
              then 'Failure' 
              else Status 
          end
```

Comment: thanks Nikola, I ended up doing something like you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4dd47/2)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE errormsgs 
(
    id          INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY
  , statusmsg   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO errormsgs (statusmsg) VALUES
  ('Success'),
  ('This is error message 1.'),
  ('Running'),
  ('This is error message 2.'),
  ('This is error message 3.'),
  ('Success'),
  ('Success'),
  ('This is error message 4.'),
  ('Running'),
  ('failure, may be'),
  ('failure, absolutely.');

;WITH statuses AS
(
    SELECT  CASE
                WHEN statusmsg NOT IN ('Success', 'Running') THEN 'Failure' 
                ELSE statusmsg 
            END status
    FROM    errormsgs
)
SELECT      status
        ,   COUNT(status) AS status_count
FROM        statuses 
GROUP BY    status;
```

*Output*:

```
STATUS   STATUS_COUNT
-------- ------------
Failure        6
Running        2
Success        3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
                     WHEN [status]='s' OR [STATUS]='r' THEN [status]
                     ELSE 'OTHER'
                END AS STATUS
      ,COUNT(1) OVER(
           PARTITION BY CASE 
                             WHEN [status]='s'
           OR [STATUS]='r' THEN [status] ELSE 'aaa' END
       ) AS 'count'
FROM   tbl2
```

[image]

Comment: This will give a count for each distinct status. The question states that all but 'Success' and 'Running' should be grouped as 'Failure'

Comment: hi Royi! that is giving me all my different errors with a count of 1. I want them grouped together

Comment: @Diego are you sure ? this query is gicing you all the counts for each error - which is not failure..... ive just tested it... do you have the right code ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir "Failure" is not a status, so Diego would want something like "Failed - Invalid paramater" and "Failed - Some Other Reason" categorised as "Failure", whereas your query would group by each of these.

Comment: I've created a fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21fbb/6 which first runs @RoyiNamir answer then Nikola's. I think Nikola's is correct.